# Is there a general name for function variables that are sent automatically?

Tags: javascript, terminology

I understand in JavaScript the *this* and *arguments* "variables" are automatically made available inside functions.  Is there a formal name for these kinds of variables that are automatically made available and don't need to be sent as parameters?

Is "variables" even the correct term for them?  Since *this* and *arguments* can be overwritten to any value, "variables" seems to fit.  But is there any term that is more specific and captures the automatic, non-parameter nature of them?

A related variable is the event object sent automatically as the first parameter to any function that is bound as an event handler (at least in the W3C model).  Is there a technical term for this kind of variable that is also sent automatically, but (unlike *this* and *arguments*) is only accessible if included in the function's parameter list?

I'm looking for a noun:
"*this* and *arguments* are both __________."

Or perhaps an adjective:
"*this* and *arguments* are ______________ variables."

The term need not be specific to JavaScript.  It may be a general programming term (such as lambda expression) that has been incorporated into the JavaScript language.

Comment: I'm not seeing a particular name in the spec but they are contextual values.  the closest I see in the spec names `this` as the `Value` of the `call` while `arguments` is the `ArgumentList`

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-call-thisargument-argumentslist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not the same thing.

`this` is a keyword. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)) And conversationally, I would probably describe it as *a keyword referring to the "current object" or "the object you're operating within".*

`arguments` is "a local variable available within all functions." ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)) Conversationally, I would personally describe it as *a magic variable.*

Answer (score 2):

One possible name might be "implicit parameter".

It is important to note though that the two parameters are treated differently. We dynamically dispatch on the `this` parameter, while the `arguments` parameter is treated like any other.

Answer (score -2):

a `Call` in javascript has 3 parameters.  `Function Object`, `This Argument` and `Arguments List`.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-call